# Столкновение материальной точки с ромбом в 2d

Tags: flash, математика, геометрия, 2d, actionscript-3

Подскажите как можно сделать проверку столкновения материальной точки с ромбом?

Гугл ответа не дает, движки типа Box2D тоже не вариант, потому что у меня там определение столкновения только одно, и было бы глупо подключать целую библиотеку для этого.

Answer (score 1):

Если это конкретный ромб с конкретными вершинами, то такая задача недавно была разобрана еще в Хэшкоде. Она достаточно тривиальна и укладывается в 4 оператора if.
[Существует](http://e-maxx.ru/upload/e-maxx_algo.pdf)(стр.254), правда, алгоритм определения принадлежности точки выпуклому многоугольнику.

Comment: да, это определенный ромб, имеет позицию, ширину и высоту, при этом соотношение сторон всегда одинаково. а вот позиция может быть разной

Comment: "Одинаковое соотношение сторон в ромбе" - это сильно и нетривиально:)

Comment: что в этом сильного и нетривиального?